# unable to start gevent

Tags: python, gevent, openerp-7

getting import error no module name greenlet, I've already installed all dependencies,
still getting this error, I am using windows 7(python26 ,openerp7). unable to solve this
error so please help me

```
D:\openerp\OpenERP\Server\server>openerp-server --gevent
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "openerp-server", line 5, in <module>
File "D:\openerp\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\cli\__init__.py", line 61, in
main
o.run(args)
File "D:\openerp\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\cli\server.py", line 285, in
run
main(args)
File "D:\openerp\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\cli\server.py", line 233, in
main
import gevent
File "D:\openerp\OpenERP\Server\server\.\gevent\__init__.py", line 49, in <mod
ule>
from gevent.greenlet import Greenlet, joinall, killall
File "D:\openerp\OpenERP\Server\server\.\gevent\greenlet.py", line 6, in <modu
le>
from gevent.hub import greenlet, getcurrent, get_hub, GreenletExit, Waiter,
kill
File "D:\openerp\OpenERP\Server\server\.\gevent\hub.py", line 30, in <module>
greenlet = __import__('greenlet').greenlet
ImportError: No module named greenlet
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you import `greenlet` from commandline in the python shell?
Looks like greenlet is missing.

Comment: yes I imported greenlet but I am not able to solve this issue